# Why are keys get pressed (stuck) for a second only in games in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, keyboard, asus-laptop

Recently, i got a new ASUS laptop with windows 10, and i noticed a weird behavior that when i press keys during games they give an effect as if they were pressed for a second and i get double movement even in menus which is really annoying and a sign of a problem somewhere.

The keyboard works fine outside of games, no long pressing effect and i would have noticed since i use this machine mainly for software development, only in games i see this effect and even if they're in window mode.

What i tried:

1. I tried multiple games and got the same effect.
2. Since the laptop has 144hz screen, i locked the game at 60fps but with no luck.
3. I tried window mode in games but didn't work either.
4. I disabled the nvidia game overlay.
5. Updated the graphics drivers.
6. Sticky keys are disabled.
7. I made a small tool to register key presses and as you can see from the attached image there are no multiple key presses of the same key outside of games.

[image]

I suspect that it has to do with the ASUS software that are preinstalled on the system but i can't pinpoint what causing the actual problem.
The laptop model is :
ASUS TUF F15 FX506LU

Any suggestions?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Does it have any relation to NumLock being on or off?

Comment: @harrymc I tried both states with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved by one or both of those things:

1. I had a bios update available, i installed it.
2. I uninstalled the keyboard drivers from device manager -> restart system -> they're automatically reinstalled by windows.

Problem solved.